# Find material for improvement of my SQL ability

Tags: sql-server

The following part that is needed to be improved is:

- script
- T-SQL
- Procedure
- Function

Problem:
Where can I get material to improve my ability in SQL coding? Is there any website for downloading a database with different task/assignment and solution?

Where should I go to review lots of SQL code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to just improve your SQL coding ability I would go to the following sites:

- http://www.sqlservercentral.com - check out the scripts section
- http://www.sqlcourse.com/index.html - this site has some good basic tutorials
- http://www.sql-tutorial.net/ - also another good site for tutorials
- http://www.mssqltips.com/ - covers a lot of different areas but still has good material
- http://blog.sqlauthority.com/ - VERY knowledgeable fella. Just search his site for what you are looking for

Here is a list of sample SQL databases for you - http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/

For some FREE reading on check out - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/books/67441/

Answer (score 1):

You can always download the [AdventureWorks](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) databases to see samples of stored procedures, functions, databases etc for SQL Server. Then you can chose any or all of the sites and labs listed at this [msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/transactsql/thread/eb14cf63-b47e-456f-b4c6-1ef4681b6577)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to start at the basics [this](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/tsqlfund2008/) is the best book. Really any book about t-SQL by [Itzik Ben-Gan](http://www.amazon.com/Itzik-Ben-Gan/e/B001IGQENW/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1) will not steer you wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to learn more about T-SQL was to try and solve real world problems. Search the web for solutions and, of course, make use of dba.stackexchange and stackoverflow sites.

If you don't have any problems to solve at the moment (lucky you) then pick up a copy of [Joe Celko's SQL Puzzles and Answers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123735963), that should keep you busy and help you learn T-SQL along the way.